# Getting 'stol' was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that gets a decimal number and turn it into a binary number (it should return it as long, so I'm converting it).
The thing is I keep get this error:

```
 "Practice.c: In function ‘std::string base2(int)’:
 Practice.c:12:29: error: ‘stol’ was not declared in this scope
 return (stol (number,0,2));"
```

That's my code, can anyone help me?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <stddef.h>
    using namespace std;

    long base2(int number) {
        string result = "";
        while(number/2 != 0) {
            result = "" + (number % 2) + result;
            number = number/2;
        }
        return (stol (number,0,2));
    }

    int main() {
        cout << base2(3) << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: look carefully on parameters of `stol` and its signature

Comment: There is _really_ no `stol(int, int, int);`...

Comment: In addition to the above comments, you need to make certain your compiler supports C++11 and is using c++11 ( add -std=c++0x to the g++ command line) to get the stoX functions.

Comment: what do you mean add -std=c++0x to the g++ command line? how should i compile it (i use g++ Practice.c when i compile)

Comment: To compile c++, you usually have to use a different file extent than ".c".  Try rename your file to "Practice.cpp"

Comment: changed it. still, how do I apply the -std=c++0x thing? where should i put/run it?